# MongoDB Query Performance using $unwind

Tags: mongodb

I have this MongoDB document structure:

```
_id: ObjectID('1234')
email: 'myEmail@gmail.com'
score: [20, 34, 45, 90...]
```

I want the global average. Across all documents and this is what I came up with:

```
const globalMeta = await tests.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      score: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$score"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      $avg: "$score"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      average: 1
    }
  }
]).toArray()
```

And the result is something like: `average: 75`

I am really concerned about performance. Would this method work if say, you had 1000's of documents?

Comment: Why can't you test and find out?

Comment: Unless you have millions of documents the performance should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(not the same but can give you some ideas):

```
 > db.tests.aggregate([
    { $project: { scores: { $avg: "$score"}, _id:0 } },
    { $group:{ _id:"Total" , FinalScoreAvg:{ $avg:"$scores"}     }}
 ])
```

Comment: That's wrong. Take this sample data: `[1,2,2,1],[10,12]`. The global average is `(1+2+2+1+10+12)/6 = 4.667` but your aggregation makes the average of averages, it yields to `((1+2+2+1)/4 + (10+12)/2) / 2 = 6.25`

Comment: Indeed I have mentioned that is not the same , just giving options  :)